# Typing a recursive function that transform data

Tags: javascript, typescript

A bit of context first: I'm retrieving data from a Postgres database with i18n fields saved as Json:

```
{
  en: "English",
  fr: "Français"
}
```

Based on the current user locale, I'd like to simplify the data and deliver only the relevant translation as a string (instead of delivering the full i18n object).

In the below example, `data` could be such raw data with all translations. `expected` would be the outcome.

```
const data = {
  int: 123,
  str: "Sun is shining",
  arr: [
    { int: 1, str: "greeting", t: { en: "Hello", fr: "Salut" } },
    { int: 2, str: "goodbye", t: { en: "Goodbye", fr: "Au revoir" } },
  ],
  obj: {
    int: 3,
    str: "Random",
    name: { en: "Name", fr: "Nom" },
    nested: [
      { int: 9, t: { en: "Nested", fr: "Imbriqué" } }
    ]
  }
}

type I18nObject = { [lang: string]: string };

function isI18nObject(value: any): value is I18nObject {
  return (
    typeof value === "object" &&
    Object.keys(value).length > 0 &&
    Object.keys(value).every((v) => v.length === 2)
  );
}

function deepTranslate(lang: string, data: any) {
  if (isI18nObject(data)) {
    return data[lang] ?? data[Object.keys(data)[0]]; // default to the first language
  } else if (Array.isArray(data)) {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      data[i] = deepTranslate(lang, data[i])
    }
    return data
    //return data.map((value) => deepTranslate(lang, value));
  } else if (typeof data === "object") {
    for (let [k, v] of Object.entries(data)) {
      data[k] = deepTranslate(lang, v)
    }
    return data
  } else {
    return data;
  }
}

const expected = deepTranslate("en", data)

console.log(expected)

/*
// with "en"
const expected = {
  int: 123,
  str: "Sun is shining",
  arr: [
    { int: 1, str: "greeting", t: "Hello" },
    { int: 2, str: "goodbye", t: "Goodbye" },
  ],
  obj: {
    int: 3,
    str: "Random",
    name: "Name",
    nested: [
      { int: 9, t: "Nested" }
    ]
  }
}
*/
```

The function works (and seems fine), but I have an issue with the resulting type. I'd like to match the original object type, but with all `I18nObject` as `string` (since they are reduced in the function to a string).

Is it even possible in the context of a recursive function ?

---

I've created a TypeScript playground if you wish to play with it: [CLICK HERE](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBvAUDGBLMKALhgEYAmAZgBocZoAnEgIgGUBXMfCegCwIIBzZrVwIGTGAG06uDPkIlS1elEnNBDAKZaoQkTGKYYWsCwASWgDZWQBgGbrWCK%20yjMYAXy%20jcxgkbkKowsgiAgcABGAJ5aBkbypiwA4uFRsQ7qAILsMNoAbiB4DB7enr4Aur4gkQBWJNh%20CkY0sqrqAEoIYHAgALYibWAIfVoNJmYwzAByI3EqjizT-aW%20uGBa0FpwJDJNcs0kAJwqCRNLm1DbmSwAkn2RDHgAjuwAl6VebRV0nlh-WCg0QADloYLdSAAOMAAeTqWmAsHQ8ikVm6ghIjCEFUxaiEXgA3FgsPZOIi8OBuBDoXDagioAAKfIudhjGDdaIAShIzNcYLwPGpsPhiMwdG0UHYDC4DLaQNBIHsMF5rLQqHQzBqdMRHgAZLq2rT6QA6ADWWmiECZLK0nONVlMgigvBgAD4YAAGGD6w0iqBmi1WlW241afJaBjRBlMzlod35e2O51q9DkTl0TlEgGksDkylwHTAgAqDG6EDRVwZaLAGPaQhUiGQJA5sca%20CVDIFQqNiIZjYQnNbbQlUq4-dR6IqMAA-NP4EgEFIe-7zZa%20wvOVIPRUKgSYAB6ffwLT2BDsKywKAgQy8MH2YrQGDVwTsBCCLS-ExWCD8jtZCQINExoCv%20pZRv2g5ik09ggAwMBVro%20BoJ6e54DAAA887IImNbOqhADU%20FDvsWGLngU7oAWWjFqWkAVloVbog2C5SOR6ZNH8TQjtKpFtIe3Fjguxp9AgwLRsGsaoO6VE0WW9GMTWKgSZmn7WD%207bwfKWiKqRKZTFq9LMMRfgwXBCGwFIppKVOOnLqGhBPJs67IJBbZNOOpoUce1ElnJSAMc%20SnsX4nF%20AJvG4N4algm5eS6KOpFEpF-zEjJvl0f5DLMKYBgQcSoCQCADr2iAgjOQOxL7gAVFgh4wAA7ngybZWAzBYAVj5aAAHqCiLbMhbYBEoVC%20CEUwcFwAp8AINaDGIEi7G08hDWQwRqKE2i6PopwWNYtirEthwwEE7ShGkMTzIYKTnRkPh0FUdBag0bQra0TRjcwXQ9CsawwMMoxLHMc1%20BsWw7NIbQHCtJxXVM0yXNcXxND8yV-FV%205AA)

Comment: Would [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wy6Pdw) work for you, then?

Comment: @caTS actually it does, but the i18n objects are not strictly `{ en: string; fr: string }`. It could be `{ en: string }`, `{ sp: string }`, `{ <any 2 letters defining a language>: string }`, { en: string, nl: string, de: string }` and so on. I understand part of the trick is this bit: `T extends { en: string; fr: string }`. Not sure how I can make it more generic.

Comment: Well, I hope you understand that then there are certain risks if that is the case (someone may use an object with two letter keys as a normal object) - but that would look like this: https://tsplay.dev/WoA98N

Comment: Yes I'm aware of the trade off. I might need to change the approach in the long run, but your solution is really helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess we should start with determining if the given object is an i18n object:

```
type Split<S, R extends readonly unknown[] = []> = S extends `${infer A}${infer B}` ? Split<B, [...R, A]> : R;

type IsI18nObject<T> = [keyof T] extends [never] ? false : string extends {
  [K in keyof T & string]: Split<K>["length"] extends 2 ? K : string
}[keyof T & string] ? false : true;
```

If `keyof T` is `never`, then it's an empty object and we say `false`. Otherwise, we "loop" over the keys of the object and check if the length of the key is 2. If it isn't we provide `string` instead of the key. Since the union will now collapse to `string` if one of the keys failed the test, we check for that and say `true` or `false` based on that.

Then the transformation is as simple as recursively checking the values if they are these i18n objects or not:

```
type Transform<T> = T extends object
  ? IsI18nObject<T> extends true
    ? string /* i18n object, replace with string */ : {
      [K in keyof T]: Transform<T[K]> // regular object
    } : T // ignore if not object at all
```

And finally, I like to move the return type of these complicated return types outside into an external signature, so it doesn't mess with our implementation:

```
function deepTranslate<T extends object>(lang: string, data: T): Transform<T>;
function deepTranslate<T extends object>(lang: string, data: T) {
    // ...
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WoA98N)

---

P.S. Consider refactoring `deepTranslate` so that it doesn't mutate `data`.